# Is $Ϝ$ an equivalence relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:ℝ→ℝ$ be a real analytic function. Let $f^{(k)}$ be the $k$th derivative of $f$. Let us define the following relation: $Ϝ:(0,1)^{k}×(0,1)^{k}→(0,1)^{k}$:

$$(t_1,t_2,...,t_{k})Ϝ(v_1,v_2,...,v_{k}) \Leftrightarrow f^{(k)}(1-2 \prod_{j=1}^{k}t_{j})=f^{(k)}(1-2 \prod_{j=1}^{k}v_{j})$$

for $k=1,...,r+1.$

Is $Ϝ$ an equivalence relation?

Comment: Why are all these $F$'s weird? $Ϝ$ seems to be a different character, but it looks the same...? Where's that coming from?

Comment: @Arkamis: This is an exercice from a local textbook.

Comment: I'm just talking about the way the symbol is appearing on my screen. In the edit box, it looks like a standard F, but rendered, it looks different.

Comment: @Arkamis: This is the $F$ from workplace Software.

Comment: It looks like the Greek letter digamma to me: $\digamma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Generalize to simplify...

For every set $S$, define a relation $R$ on $S$ by $sRt$ if and only if $\varphi(s)=\varphi(t)$ for every function $\varphi$ in some collection $\Phi$. Then $R$ is an equivalence relation on $S$.

Simplify further by considering the case when $\Phi$ is a singleton, then prove that this case is actually the general case.

Comment: @ Did : How I can find equivalence classes in this case?.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your question. You might want to explain.

Comment: @ Did: What are the equivalence classes or the quotient set of the relation defined in my question.

Comment: In the setting of the last sentence of my answer, the equivalence classes of $R$ are the sets $\Phi^{-1}(\alpha)\subseteq S$ for some $\alpha$ in $\Phi(S)$.

Comment: Ok and thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Since The relation $Ϝ$  is defined by $" ="$ the equality relation  which is obviously an equivalent relation then $Ϝ$ is also an equivalent relation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In general, if you have a function $g: A\to B$, then the relation $F$ on $A\times A$ given by $aFa' \Leftrightarrow g(a) = g(a')$ is an equivalence relation.  The quotient $A/F$ is the image of $g$ in $B$.

Your question is about the specific function $g: (0,1)^{r+1}\to \mathbb{R}^r$ sending $(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{r+1})$ to $(f'(1-2t_1), f''(1-2t_1t_2),\ldots, f^{(r)}(1-2t_1\cdots t_r))$.

Comment: @ Owen Biesel : How I can find equivalence classes in this case?.